# pass the JSON data with JSONP

Tags: json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to pass a json data with **dsfut.net** API and display some information on a page. Unfortunately i get an error like:

> SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

And this is my code:

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    $id = return_theme_setting('dsfut_id');
    $key = return_theme_setting('dsfut_key');
?>
<script>
    var fifa = <?php echo $_POST['fifa_ver']; ?>;
    var platform = '<?php echo $_POST['console']; ?>';
    var partner_id = '<?php echo $id; ?>'; 
    var timestamp = <?php echo $timestamp; ?>;
    var signature = '<?php echo md5($id.$key.$timestamp); ?>';

    var url = 'https://dsfut.net/api/'+fifa+'/'+platform+'/'+partner_id+'/'+timestamp+'/'+signature+'?format=jsonp';

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain : true,
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);},
        error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
            alert(status+" "+exception);
        }
    });
</script>
```

What is wrong here?